# SQL error on mamp server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found. 
How to fix this using the Mamp server?
I don't understand why this keeps coming up :/ Eventhough it says the innodb table can't be found, I can find them in mysql folder.

I've tried to look online for the solution but don't know if they are relevant to my problem.

---

```
170204 19:40:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from     /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56

2017-02-04 19:40:02 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).

2017-02-04 19:40:02 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.33) starting as process 82357 ...

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.33 started; log sequence number 7445589

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 8889

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] IPv6 is available.

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events

2017-02-04 19:40:02 82357 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '5.6.33'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 8889  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

2017-02-04 19:40:18 700009bfa000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.

2017-02-04 19:40:18 700009bfa000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "registration"."goal" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
```

Comment: have you try to start **mysql_upgrade** to fix it ??

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all of this! I would I go about doing that?

Comment: try this from console. i am not sure where MySQL is installed : **/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/mysql_upgrade**

Comment: Just tried that but nothing happens :/

Comment: Did the command run correctly and just not fix the problem, did you get a message that the command wasn't found, or did it fail to run?

Comment: The command wasn't found. However, it somehow works now so I'm hoping the problem won't happen again!